# Desire2Learn: How Can i attach the file with New Post in Discussions?

Tags: ios, desire2learn

I can create a new post in Discussions using the following feed

```
Feed: host/d2l/api/le/(D2LVERSION: version)/(D2LID: orgUnitId)/discussions/forums/(D2LID: forumId)/topics/(D2LID: topicId)/posts/
Content-Type:"application/json"
http-Metohd:POST

 http-body:{
    "ParentPostId": null,
    "Subject": "IOS  Testing",
    "Message": {"Content": "ios Test meassage","Type": "Text"},
    "IsAnonymous": "false"
 }
```

How can i attach the file with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API does not provide a way to upload files to an existing discussion post. Once created, you can [only update the post's Subject and Message components](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/discuss.html#Discussions.UpdatePostData).

To create a new discussion post with attachments, you send a multipart-post body. The *first* part in the body [should be your post's data](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/discuss.html#Discussions.CreatePostData) as in your example. Subsequent parts can contain the [file data for one or more attachments](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/basic/fileupload.html#simple-uploads) and should follow the RFC2388 multi-part mixed methodology (because the first part is JSON data, and the subsequent part(s) are binary data).